# Visually developing web page in WebMatrix

Tags: html, css, web, webmatrix

I have installed WebMatrix to my computer, and started to learn how to create Website. Yeah, I am new to the Web development. However, I am a bit confused about how to create a webpage in WebMatrix.

While developing user interface to my Java application, I use visual builder and put containers where I like to put, and then implement functionality that it uses.

Do I have chance to visually develop web page like I did for Java application? I prefer to visually design webpage, and then implement functionality of each parts. Do I need to install other tools, if yes what?

(I am trying to develop web page for my personal github page. I plan to publish blog post about projects I have. )

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with WebMatrix. It only allows you to edit text files in your server.

I would suggest learning to code HTML. It is not that hard.
http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web

Comment: Do professional web development software, which is costly to buy, **only** have visual design tool?

Comment: Most of them render the code you write in real time. All of them allow you to edit the HTML code as text.